# linq: aggregate into single line (flatten)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, flatten

I am currently using a linq and accessing some meta data using a for loop:

```
public SignUpMeta GetSignUpMeta(User user)
{
    var users = (from u in User
                where user.Email == u.Email || user.UserName == u.UserName
                select u);
    var result = new SignUpMeta();
    foreach (var u in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == u.Email) result.IsDuplicateEmail = true;
        if (user.UserName == u.UserName) result.IsDuplicateUserName = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way for the `Linq` to generate the `SignUpMeta` directly? 
This function is inside the `DBContext` class and I am looking for a way to get the exact data directly from the db (without raw sql).

**Update:**
The `User` is `DbSet` and the whole code runs inside the db context class. I am trying to write something that will make EF fetch the value directly in a single query.

**Update 2:**
The SQL equivalent of what I am looking for would be:

```
SELECT MAX(username), MAX(email)
(SELECT CAST((UserName = @user) AS bit) username, 
        CAST((Email = @email) AS bit) email
 FROM User WHERE UserName = @user OR Email = @email)
```

**Update 3:**
SignUpMeta object that needs to be fetched contains the metadata that provides information required for server side validation.

The above `C#` code runs a query that fetches up to two columns in this instance. When there are more such conditions, there would be more lines. I am trying to find a way that EF would give only the two booleans alone in a single record.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be your real code. Why would you have a collection called `User` and a type called `User`?

Comment: I did copy the code directly. `User` isn't a collection, it's a DBSet. This code is inside the db context

Comment: Yeah this is a bit of moving target, do you just want results where there are duplicates, how many users are there. do you want all of them? if you are working with the whole set of users, how much data in the metadata is a subset of users. I mean you might want to project just the properties you want dynamically and work with that, if there are 1000s of users. or if there are not many users and a simple user model then you could just suck the model back and work with it in memory

Comment: Basically a single `SignUpMeta` object that contains the information of if the username and email is existing in the database. The object is meant to be used for validating before signing up the user

Comment: Ahh ok well that made all the difference, and you should really make the domain of your question extremely clear in future, otherwise we put work into helping you, and people come and downvote answers when the domain becomes clearer. anyway good luck

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes, i do notice the down votes. I was under the impression that the "signup" part would imply the rest. I'll be clear in future

Comment: for the record to all, thanks for all the effort in the answers, I didn't downvote any

Answer (score 0):

This'll be my try, if you truly must use LINQ:

```
from u in stuff.Users
group u by 0 into grp
select new
{
    IsDuplicateEmail = grp.Any(x => x.Email == user.Email),
    IsDuplicateUserName = grp.Any(x => x.UserName == user.UserName)
}
```

Entity Framework will translate that into sub-selects. If you're using SQL Server and have both columns indexed, this should result in the same amount of I/O as your sample SQL.

I don't believe there is any query that will generate your desired sample SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `FirstOrDefault` on this and got the right output. However when i checked the sql it ran, it basically got the user table from the db. It ran the query `SELECT <everything> FROM user AS u0 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane which version of EF are you running? I just checked with 6 and it doesn't do that.

Comment: I am using EF Core for SQL Server

Comment: Ah. I know Core does not yet have the same level of query optimization that non-Core has. If you add your `where` clause back in to before the `group by`, I wonder if that'll help?

Comment: nop. now the `First` makes it query a single row but it is still selecting all columns

Comment: @NevilleNazerane that’s because the use of `Any` in the projection - there is no specific fields being selected so the library can’t optimize. As I said in my answer (now deleted) your original code with a slight tweak is the most efficient way of doing this, EF can only provide so much, it’s designed for convenience not speed.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will be the fastest query:

```
public SignUpMeta GetSignUpMeta(User user)
{
    return new SignUpMeta()
    {
        IsDuplicateEmail = User.Where(u => u.Email == user.Email).Take(1).Any(),
        IsDuplicateUserName = User.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName).Take(1).Any(),
    };
}
```

Caching on the DB server should make the two queries quite fast.

Comment: I would love some feedback on why this deserves a down-vote.

Comment: Didn’t downvote but I think it may be related to the fact this solution involves 2 trips to the DB when really it could be done in one.

Comment: @James - Yes, I appreciate there are two round trips. I'm expecting the extra delay to be mitigated by the fact that when there are no duplicates this query returns zero records and should cache quite nicely.

Comment: @James - Also, this is a sign-up screen. The query does not need to scale (how many users will be signing up simultaneously?) and users expect delays when signing up. I totally accept that you generally wouldn't do this if scaling was a factor.

Comment: unfortunately those are elements of the application we aren’t privy too and therefore shouldn’t make assumptions. Your making assumptions about the DB when queries like this can be very slow based on size & indexing. Also, we can’t be sure on the use case here, is this a typeahead? If so, this could be multiple calls and for good UX would require a fast response. Eitherway, 1 trip is always going to be faster than 2 ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote either but yes, might be the 2 calls. are you sure db caching will make up for the network overhead of 2 queries? Also i don't see the use of `Take` in this context

Comment: @James - My logic is that users expect 400ms delays. If this makes the queries go from 10ms to 20ms then the user won't care. Simpler code is often worth these kinds of choices.